# Get the current year in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

How do I get the current year in JavaScript?

Comment: Astonishing if there really isn't a duplicate for this. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562587/shortest-way-to-print-current-year-in-javascript) is close, but not exact.

Comment: Note that the "current" year is not necessarily the same for everyone on the planet at the same time.  One has to consider time zone.  Most of the answers here give the current year in the user's local time zone (assuming the code is running in a web browser).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortest way to print current year in a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562587/shortest-way-to-print-current-year-in-a-website)

Comment: So everyone look out for those 24 hours out of 8760 where this is not true!  My uncle lost a toe not heeding this advice!

Answer (score 2645, accepted):

Create a **[`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)** object and call **[`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)**:

```
new Date().getFullYear()  // returns the current year
```

---

**Example usage:** a page footer that always shows the current year:

```js
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
```

```css
footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    © <span id="year"></span> by Stack Overflow
</footer>
```

See also, the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor's **[full list of methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#static_methods)**.

Comment: For other functions in the same family, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Getter

Comment: To get the year according to universal time use [getUTCFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear)

Comment: The footer example above would be more clear if it were just: <footer>
    <span id="year"></span> 
</footer>

Comment: it is currently december 25th of 2023 and this outputs 2024

Answer (score 310):

```
// Return today's date and time
var currentTime = new Date()

// returns the month (from 0 to 11)
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1

// returns the day of the month (from 1 to 31)
var day = currentTime.getDate()

// returns the year (four digits)
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

// write output MM/dd/yyyy
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
```

Comment: Links: [getFullYear()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp) | [getDate()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp) | [getMonth()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp)

Comment: Use getFullYear() instead of getYear(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296897/whats-the-difference-between-javascripts-getyear-and-getfullyear-functions

Answer (score 126):

Here is another method to get date

```
new Date().getDate()          // Get the day as a number (1-31)
new Date().getDay()           // Get the weekday as a number (0-6)
new Date().getFullYear()      // Get the four digit year (yyyy)
new Date().getHours()         // Get the hour (0-23)
new Date().getMilliseconds()  // Get the milliseconds (0-999)
new Date().getMinutes()       // Get the minutes (0-59)
new Date().getMonth()         // Get the month (0-11)
new Date().getSeconds()       // Get the seconds (0-59)
new Date().getTime()          // Get the time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970)
```

Answer (score 37):

You can get the current year with one line of JS code.

```html
<p>Copyright <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script></p>
```

Answer (score 16):

Such is how I have it embedded and outputted to my HTML web page:

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="text-center">Copyright &copy; 
        <script>
            var CurrentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
            document.write(CurrentYear)
        </script>
    </p>
</div>
```

Output to HTML page is as follows:

Copyright © 2018

Comment: You shouldn't use document.write() but instead something like innerHTML of a span

Comment: The main thing here is the var CurrentYear = new Date().getFullYear().  The document.write() is secondary, and of course various other solutions exist.  You should not mark down my reputation for this.

Comment: 1.) Bad practice says you, but others disagree since this is valid vanilla Javascript; 2.) My answer provides new information of how to implement this within an HTML page, and not just console.log().

Comment: *Valid* as in *working* not *valid* as in *good*. See the accepted answer for the correct way of doing this

Comment: "Good" is subjective.  There is more than one way to skin a cat, and more than one way to solve coding problems.  If the solution is simple and works, then why is this not "good" in your humble opinion?

Comment: Well, sir, it is clear that this is not a clear-cut objective standard (and indeed is an open debate), as there are many who disagree with you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

...and also here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789190/why-not-document-write

Therefore, your marking my reputation down for your subjective opinion is not very nice since there are others who would disagree with you.  Remember the main point here, and that I just provided a simple way to print this to HTML file instead of console.log().

Comment: Please see the previous two links where you can see HUNDREDS of people who disagree with you.  There are also HUNDREDS of people who agree with you, so it is not a clear-cut issue.  You insistence upon your way or the high way is quite closed-minded since you cannot be certain if someone may decide that document.write() is the best solution for his/her needs.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use javascript like this. Otherwise you can use [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/) Plugin which helps in large application.

```
new Date().getDate()          // Get the day as a number (1-31)
new Date().getDay()           // Get the weekday as a number (0-6)
new Date().getFullYear()      // Get the four digit year (yyyy)
new Date().getHours()         // Get the hour (0-23)
new Date().getMilliseconds()  // Get the milliseconds (0-999)
new Date().getMinutes()       // Get the minutes (0-59)
new Date().getMonth()         // Get the month (0-11)
new Date().getSeconds()       // Get the seconds (0-59)
new Date().getTime()          // Get the time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970)
```

```js
function generate(type,element)
{
 var value = "";
 var date = new Date();
 switch (type) {
  case "Date":
   value = date.getDate();  // Get the day as a number (1-31)
   break;
  case "Day":
   value = date.getDay();  // Get the weekday as a number (0-6)
   break;
  case "FullYear":
   value = date.getFullYear(); // Get the four digit year (yyyy)
   break;
  case "Hours":
   value = date.getHours(); // Get the hour (0-23)
   break;
  case "Milliseconds":
   value = date.getMilliseconds(); // Get the milliseconds (0-999)
   break;
  case "Minutes":
   value = date.getMinutes();     // Get the minutes (0-59)
   break;
  case "Month":
   value = date.getMonth(); // Get the month (0-11)
   break;
  case "Seconds":
   value = date.getSeconds(); // Get the seconds (0-59)
   break;
  case "Time":
   value = date.getTime();  // Get the time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970)
   break;
 }

 $(element).siblings('span').text(value);
}
```

```css
li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

button{
  width: 150px;
}

span{
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
 <li>
  <button type="button" onclick="generate('Date',this)">Get Date</button>
  <span></span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <button type="button" onclick="generate('Day',this)">Get Day</button>
  <span></span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <button type="button" onclick="generate('FullYear',this)">Get Full Year</button>
  <span></span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <button type="button" onclick="generate('Hours',this)">Get Hours</button>
  <span></span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <button type="button" onclick="generate('Milliseconds',this)">Get Milliseconds</button>
  <span></span>
 </li>

 <li>
  <button type="button" onclick="generate('Minutes',this)">Get Minutes</button>
  <span></span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <button type="button" onclick="generate('Month',this)">Get Month</button>
  <span></span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <button type="button" onclick="generate('Seconds',this)">Get Seconds</button>
  <span></span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <button type="button" onclick="generate('Time',this)">Get Time</button>
  <span></span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

for current year we can use **getFullYear() from Date** class however there are many function which you can use as per the requirements, some functions are as,

```js
var now = new Date()
console.log("Current Time is: " + now);

// getFullYear function will give current year 
var currentYear = now.getFullYear()
console.log("Current year is: " + currentYear);

// getYear will give you the years after 1990 i.e currentYear-1990
var year = now.getYear()
console.log("Current year is: " + year);

// getMonth gives the month value but months starts from 0
// add 1 to get actual month value 
var month = now.getMonth() + 1
console.log("Current month is: " + month);

// getDate gives the date value
var day = now.getDate()
console.log("Today's day is: " + day);
```

Answer (score 3):

Take this example, you can place it wherever you want to show it without referring to script in the footer or somewhere else like other answers

```
<script>new Date().getFullYear()>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>
```

Copyright note on the footer as an example

```
Copyright 2010 - <script>new Date().getFullYear()>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>
```

Comment: This is an unnecessary answer.

Comment: is the same as the answer of Jerusalem Programmer slightly different

Comment: the question is just get the year in JS, not get the year and place it in the footer.
And inn that case, you could have edited the other answer. 

Anyway...

Comment: I looks a lot like what can be found on this website : http://updateyourfooter.com/

Answer (score 3):

Instantiate the class **Date** and call upon its **getFullYear** method to get the current year in **yyyy** format.
Something like this:

```
let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
```

The **currentYear** variable will hold the value you are looking out for.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Most of the answers found here are correct **only** if you need the current year based on your **local** machine's time zone and offset (client side) - source which, in most scenarios, cannot be considered reliable (beause it can differ from machine to machine).

Reliable sources are:

- Web server's clock (but make sure that it's updated)
- Time APIs & CDNs

## Details

A method called on the `Date` instance will return a value based on the local time of your machine.

Further details can be found in "MDN web docs": [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

For your convenience, I've added a relevant note from their docs:

> (...) the basic methods to fetch the date and time or its components all work in the local (i.e. host system) time zone and offset.

Another source mentioning this is: [JavaScript date and time object](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php)

> it is important to note that if someone's clock is off by a few hours or they are in a different time zone, then the Date object will create a different times from the one created on your own computer.

Some reliable sources that you can use are:

- Your web server's clock (check if it's accurate first)
- Time APIs & CDNs:

  - https://timezonedb.com/api
  - http://worldtimeapi.org
  - http://worldclockapi.com
  - http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html
  - Other related APIs: https://www.programmableweb.com/category/time/api

But if you simply don't care about the time accuracy or if your use case requires a time value relative to local machine's time then you can safely use Javascript's `Date` basic methods like `Date.now()`, or `new Date().getFullYear()` (for current year).

Answer (score 2):

Grabbing the class, we can replace it's textContent with year in javascript:

```js
document.querySelector(".yr").textContent = (new Date().getFullYear());
```

```html
&copy; <span class="yr"></span> Company. All Rights Reserved.
```

Answer (score 2):

In React, you can use inline js

```js
<p class="font-inter text-sm text-gray-500 lg:mt-0">
    © Copyright {new Date().getFullYear()}. All rights reserved.
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the ES6 Javascript with frameworks like Angular, React, VueJS. Then you should integrate a third-party utility library for your project convenience. `DayJS` is one of the most popular and lightweight library with Immutable data structures.
In `dayJS` you can get `year` in one simple line of code like below.

```
dayjs().year()
```

There is also a bunch of useful methods as well. So I would suggest you to use the dayjs for your next project.