# Why not document.write?

Tags: javascript

Why is it generally not considered good practice to use `document.write` in Javascript? I know it is not the most elegant or best way to do it, but are there any true errors with it? Is it ever ok? And in what case would it be better than `inner.HTML`

I understand that it will rewrite the document, if used after the loading. However, should I be using `innerHTML` even if I am trying to rewrite the document? If so, why?

I know some have asked if I even looked at the related questions before posting; I did. But I did not find anything satisfactory.

Comment: Your answer is here I guess, it is about performance.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13499903/1517542

Comment: downvoting for the lack of research. Did you even look the related question list before posting?

Comment: Yes, I did look at it. I think my wording was strange, or something, because I saw nothing like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used *correctly*, it's fine, but of very limited use.

You [can't use it in XHTML](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite), but I would recommend not using XHTML anyway unless you have a really, really good reason to.

The problem comes when you call `document.write` after the initial page load is complete. *During* page load is fine, but afterward, it causes an implicit `document.open`, which clears the document from the window and starts fresh.

Using `document.write` also means you can't demand-load your scripts or use the [`async` or `defer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) attributes on your script elements.

Finally, I usually recommend putting your JavaScript in a separate (single) JavaScript file at the very end of the document (just before the closing `</body>` tag). If you want to use `document.write` to output to the page, you'd have to include that script file higher up or use code directly within the HTML, neither both of which I recommend against.

So since it's of such limited use compared with other methods, it's best to get proficient with the other methods.

Comment: Why can't it be used in XHTML?

Comment: @Melab: See https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite

Answer (score 2):

yeah, calling document.write after the document has finished loading will wipe the document. Fire up your console, and do a `document.write("test")` call. The page will get overwritten with this new content. Except maybe for setting iframe innerHTML in a single step, never use `document.write`.

Answer (score 1):

One reason can be that `document.write` does not work in XHTML

Also `document.write` only works while the page is loading; If you call it after the page is done loading, it will overwrite the whole page ie, after your document has been full rendered and closed, using `document.write()` will clear your current document and start a new one, wiping out all previous content.

Answer (score 1):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) :

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling
>   document.open() will automatically perform a document.open call. Once
>   you have finished writing, it is recommended to call document.close(),
>   to tell the browser to finish loading the page. The text you write is
>   parsed into the document's structure model. In the example above, the
>   h1 element becomes a node in the document.

In short : code that must be executed past the initial `load` (for example in an event handler) can't include a `document.write` or they trigger a replacement of the whole document.

Answer (score 1):

Because it replaces entire document. In 99% of cases you just need to replace content of some specific elements.

document.write does have it uses - for example when you need to write an executable script to a newly created document.

Answer (score 1):

As a good pratice, sometimes we have information on the client side and using javascript we write these informations in `div` and `span` elements because they are in the right position of the html layout. And as the guys said, `document.write` does not work with xhtml.