# What is the most lightweight way to show the current year in my footer?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a `copyright (c) 2014` notice in my footer.

But I want it to cycle through all the years/months/days without me having to change that.

I have a `_footer.html.erb` partial where I am doing this.

The obvious easy answer is just to say `<%= Time.now.year %>`.

That means that every time the view is loaded, it has to do a Ruby call at the end. It seems kinda expensive, considering that this will appear on every single page of the site and it will have to make a Ruby call for every single load.

Is there a more lightweight/streamlined way, where maybe the value can be cached and be displayed from the cache?

Comment: you can fragment_cache the footer

Comment: Retrieving a value from the cache seems more expensive than a call to `Time.now.year`

Comment: the copyright is intended to be the year the copy was written so should be static as 2014. No?

Comment: @Stefan Is that so? How would I test that?

Comment: @Yule that's an interesting perspective.

Comment: @marcamillion see [toro2k's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23515249/477037)

Comment: @Stefan thanks for the tip - I hadn't refreshed the page and it didn't tell me there were answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shoudn't trust your intuition when it comes to performances, it is wiser to measure.

The following example compares the time taken to compute `Time.now.year` with the time taken to extract the value from Redis or Memcached:

```
require 'redis'
R = Redis.new
R.set('year', Time.now.year)

require 'memcached'
M = Memcached.new
M.set('year', Time.now.year)

require 'fruity'
compare(
  compute:  -> { Time.now.year },
  redis:    -> { R.get('year').to_i },
  memcache: -> { M.get('year') }
)
```

Output:

```
Running each test 256 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
compute is faster than memcache by 11x ± 1.0
memcache is faster than redis by 3x ± 0.1
```

That said, just call `Time.now.year`, it wouldn't worth find an alternative.

Comment: TIL about fruity. Looks very useful. Link for others: https://github.com/marcandre/fruity

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= cache 'time_of_year', expires_in: 1.day do %>
    <%= Time.now.year %>
<%= end %>
```

Read more here. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

IMO, I don't think this will make it any faster though, could even be slower.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am just going to go with vanilla `Time.now.year` for now...but if I ever need fragment caching like this I will come back to this answer. Thanks much!

Comment: @marcamillion Consider marking it as an answer though.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure it is faster to recalculate `Time.now.year` at every request.

Fetching that value from a cache will result in loading a file from a disk or a connection to a service like memcached via socket. That sound to me way more expensive than doing this simple `Time.now.year` calculation.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry to much for that but if you must optimize it you could have something like that in your `ApplicationHelper`:

```
def current_year
  @year ||= Time.now.year
end
```

and use `current_year` in your views.

You could also use a simple [caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) to avoid the call altogether.

Personally I find both approaches an overkill which take away from readability/maintainability for no good reason :)

Answer (score 1):

[You could use Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002254/get-the-current-year-in-javascript), like so:

```
 var currentyear = new Date().getFullYear();
 $(".element").html(currentyear);
```

Or a better way will be to use what `@iceman` suggested (caching)