# Javascript getCurrentYear in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I'm trying to display current year in a JSP page using JS.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                document.write(getCurrentYear());
</script>
```

But this is not working and gives an error.

(index):98 Uncaught ReferenceError: getCurrentYear is not defined
    at (index):98

Can someone please help.

Comment: Have you actually defined the method `getCurrentYear` anywhere?

Comment: did you define getCurrentYear () method ?

Comment: um https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002254/get-the-current-year-in-javascript

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem you are facing is due to ->

**getCurrentYear** is not a global function(by Javascript) so it is  not defined and you might not  have defined it

but creating Date object and calling it's function **getFullYear**  will definitely work.

**Code Snippet**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined getcurrentyear() inside your script tag??