# Javascript function to count the number of year passed since

Tags: javascript, count

I want to find the number of years passed since 2017. i jsut need the years not the month of this current year.

Comment: This might get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002254/get-the-current-year-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date().getFullYear() - 2017;
```