# Print current year timestamp in HTML via JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to print the current year next to my copyright in my footer, but it's not working.
The `"Name "` will be replaced by my brand name.

```
<div class="footer-content-3">
    <i class="far fa-copyright"></i>
    <h4 id="copyright-year"></h4>
</div>

<script>
    var year = getFullYear();
    document.getElementById('copyright-year').innerHTML = ("Name " + year);
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the current year in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002254/get-the-current-year-in-javascript)

Comment: `getFullYear()` is not a global method, but a method of a `Date` object.  So... `var year = (new Date()).getFullYear()`. However it would be much better to have the copyright in the real HTML source, not just on screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use date before use getfullyear

```js
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();

document.getElementById('copyright-year').innerHTML = ("Name " + year);
```

```html
<div class="footer-content-3">
  <i class="far fa-copyright"></i>
  <h4 id="copyright-year"></h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
new Date().getFullYear()
```

in the place of your:

```
getFullYear()
```

to get the correct full year.

Comment: it is correct, however, from my point of view, it is always better to already have the possibility to add for example the month or day so if you want you can also use it in other areas

Comment: **Thank you** for improving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must have to use Date object:

```
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();
```