# JavaScript dynamic year not printing on PDF using MadCap Flare, but works fine on HTML

Tags: javascript, pdf

I want to print dynamic year using JavaScript, which works fine on the HTML documents, but when they are published for PDF, the year is not displaying.

I am using a software called MadCap Flare, which is a help file generation tool.

Below is my code that I have used.

```
<p>© <script type="text/javascript">document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script><a class="copy" href="#" target="_blank">Abc</a>. Trademarks.</p>
```

I have referred to the below Stackoverflow question.

[Shortest way to print current year in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562587/shortest-way-to-print-current-year-in-javascript)

It works perfectly fine when the HTML are tested on browsers, but they are not printing on PDF.

Comment: The important piece of information is how you are publishing for PDF. I doubt that the PDF generator executes javascript.

Comment: I am using a software called MadCap Flare, which is a help file generation tool. So I am creating my HTML documents, which can be published for PDF as well. The same script is getting executed, when I am using a generic footer on all the PDF files, but this file is coming from an HTML file that I have created and strangely it is not working. If it was not understanding execution, it would have not printed the same on footer. - @Popnoodles

Comment: What are you using to create the PDF not the HTML?

Comment: The same software, Madcap Flare - @Popnoodles

Comment: Check Madcap Flare support to see if their PDF generator parses javascript. I doubt it does.